# How do I get rid of recursion in my Nim programme in Java?

Tags: java

I'm making the game of Nim, and I know I've experienced recursion somewhere, but I'm not sure on how to fix it. Can someone give me a hand?
Below is the code you should need, but I can get more if needed.

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void changeDisplay() {
    //checks if the group picked equals one of the existing groups.
    if(groupPick.contentEquals("A") || groupPick.contentEquals("a")) {
        //checks if the group is equal to 0, avoids cheating.
        if(a == 0) {
            System.out.println("Nice try " + playerName + ", you can't take something from nothing.");
            gamePlaying();
        } else {
            //checks if the number picked is greater than the amount of elements in the group selected.
            while(numPick > a) {
                System.out.print("Error, you cannot take more than what is there. Please pick again: ");
                numPick = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            }

        }
```

skipped some if statements.

```
} else {
        //runs this code if the group the player selected isn't a pre-existing group.
        System.out.println("Oops! "+ groupPick + " doesn't seem to be a group, please select a group (A, B, or C).");
        System.out.print(playerName + ", choose a pile: ");
        groupPick = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        changeDisplay();
    }
        playerPicker++;
        display();
    }
```

Comment: what is problem? Does not work as expected or is there an exception?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of recursion? What's the actual problem you're having?

Comment: _skipped some if statements_ ... I have a feeling that we need those if-statements since you call `changeDisplay()` again in it without a condition. Please post at least the if-statement right before the else.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have no issue with it, my programme ran smoothly, but my programming instructor told me to avoid recursion, as it could lead to problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut out the recursion, you either need to

A) Change changeDisplay to return a bool indicating if it is still dirty (needs to be called again)

or

B) wrap the changeDisplay function's contents in a `while(true) {...}` to repeat the process, using return/break to stop when it is done.